# How can I safely use semaphores in a while loop?

Tags: java, synchronization, semaphore, try-finally

In the following code fragment I'm using a semaphore to synchronize access to certain resources.

```
public void m () {
    permit.acquire ();
    while (!canFoo ()) {
        permit.release ();
        reticulateSpines ();
        permit.acquire ();
    }
    doFoo ();
    permit.release ();
}
```

It might be reasonable to enclose the acquire/release cycles in a try/finally. How can I do this, given the presence of the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the principle of every `acquire` **must** be released I would suggest:

```
private final Semaphore permit = new Semaphore(8, true);
private final Random random = new Random();

private boolean canFoo() {
    return random.nextBoolean();
}

private void doFoo() {
    System.out.println("Foo done!");
}

private void reticulateSpines() {
    System.out.println("Spines reticulated!");
}

public void m() throws InterruptedException {
    permit.acquire();
    try {
        while (!canFoo()) {
            permit.release();
            try {
                reticulateSpines ();
            } finally {
                permit.acquire();
            }
        }
        doFoo();
    } finally {
        permit.release();
    }
}
```

However - I am not sure of you are using Semaphores as they are intended. It looks much more like you are looking for something like `ReentrantLock` which would eliminate spinlock loop.

```
ReadWriteLock fooLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
Lock fooReadLock = fooLock.readLock();
Lock fooWriteLock = fooLock.writeLock();

public void n() throws InterruptedException {
    fooWriteLock.lock();
    try {
        doFoo();
    } finally {
        fooWriteLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

or even perhaps

```
public void o() throws InterruptedException {
    while (!fooWriteLock.tryLock()) {
        reticulateSpines();
    }
    try {
        doFoo();
    } finally {
        fooWriteLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: (I've added a method call (which does not require sync) in the center.)

Comment: I think this structure is a good idea, but I find the `try .. finally { acquire }` quite strange. I'm not sure, but is that the right way to handle the case of a possible exception in the center?

Comment: @mafu - The same principle applies - if you have acquired the semaphore you **must** release it but once you have acquired it and you choose to release it you **must** acquire it again or you may end up releasing an unacquired semaphore in the outer finally. This code will always leave the semaphore in the same state it found it, even when interrupted.

Comment: In case the inner acquire blocks, then gets interrupted by a `Thread.interrupt()`, the outer finally is run without prior permit acquisition.

Comment: Ah, you could mitigate that by adding a boolean flag which is cleared right before the inner release and activated right after the inner acquire, and the outer finally only releases if that flat is set. It would look bloated, but it should be 'correct'.

Comment: @mafu - Yes that is an edge case that could bite you and yes, a flag could be used to mitigate. However, as I suggested, you should revisit your intent in case there was another mechanism that would achieve your aims with more elegance.

Comment: @mafu - Perhaps a [Fixed Threadpool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) would achieve what you want. Essentially you code ensures that no more than a certain number of threads are foo-ing at any one time.